# How much longer to thaw an elephant than a chicken?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, thermal-conduction

Twenty-five years ago I came across this question on a physics olympics exam and I've never really worked out a satisfactory answer... How much longer does it take to thaw an elephant than a chicken?

I got as far as making the following simplifying assumptions:

- They are both frozen spheres of meat at a uniform -1°C
- "meat" basically has the same thermal characteristics as water except that it maintains its shape when liquid
- The chicken has a radius of 10cm and the elephant has a radius of 1m
- They're surrounded by a fluid uniformly maintained at a steady 20°C
- "thawed" is defined as "the center has reached +1 celsius"
- We have to take into account the fact that heat transfer rate is proportional to cross-section, which varies with time in this 3d case
- We have to take into account the latent heat of fusion while part of the sphere is actually melting

Beyond that I was never able to set up the heat-flow equations to get a satisfactory answer...

Comment: This is, in effect, a problem of cooling by radiation. Are the chicken and the elephant assumed to be spheres?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Characteristic time for heat diffusion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/371939/)

Comment: This question is hugely different to the alternative question pointed to. First, this is 3D analysis while the other is 1D. Heat transfer rate is proportional to cross sectional area and this question the cross section varies while in the other, it does not. This question involves two materials, ice and water. Ice conducts heat approximately 4 times faster than water and the interface boundary between the two is continuously moving, while the other question only involves one material.  There is also the latent heat of fusion of converting the ice to water, that is not in the other question.

Comment: The linked "duplicate" definitely doesn't answer my question, agreed @ KDP. And @StutiGupta yes, I specifically said we can assume them to be spheres :)

Comment: Hi, I think that there is a simpler approach to all of this. Suppose you would heat them in a microwave oven with fixed power output and efficiency. Then the ratio in time is just the ratio in heat capacity between the two animals (mostly the latent one), which is effectively their ratio in mass

Comment: Voting to reopen, The linked question is definitely not a duplicate.

Comment: P.S. Since we are approximating, it might be conceptually easier to have cubical chickens and cows. From each face of the cube, the heat conducts from the square base to the centre, in a pyramid shaped conduction channel. Since the cells trap the water in cells, convection can largely be ignored, unlike a large vessel of water.

Comment: IMO, this is not any different than any of the other "do my work for me" kind of problems that we close regularly. Probably not a dupe, but it seems hardly worth opening since it'll just get closed as HW-like anyway.

Comment: @nicolaskruchten Do you know what Newton's law of cooling is?